# Can't move cursor to submenu on mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a menu with sub menu created, and only thing I did is sub menu is placed outside the `UL` (because I had no choice), the problem is I can't move cursor to sub menu, I tried to check if there is any disconnect with menu and sub menu, but no clue..

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/qsyg958b/) working demo

**CSS**

```
<style>
.nav{ float: right; margin: 22px 0 0; padding: 0; }
.nav ul{ float: right; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 16px; }
.nav ul li{ float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; /*position: relative;*/ display:block; padding:0 0 40px 0;}
.nav > ul > li > a{ color: #771521; padding:8px 15px 8px 15px; }
.nav ul li a:hover{text-decoration: underline;}

/*-----------Sub menu -----------*/
.submenu_willwid{position:absolute; width:100%; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.65); top:90px; padding:10px; box-sizing:border-box; display:none; z-index:101; min-height:195px; box-shadow:0px 7px 8px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.68); left:0;}
.menu_inner{width:100%; max-width:1200px; margin:0 auto;}
.submenu_col_full{width:20%; float:left;}
.submenu_col_full > h4{font-size:14px; color:#fff; text-transform:uppercase; font-weight:400; text-align:center; padding:0 0 10px 0;}
.submenu_col_full > h4 > a{color:#fff; text-decoration:none;}
.submenu_willwid:after, .submenu_willwid:before {bottom: 100%; left: 51.5%; border: solid transparent; content: " "; height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; pointer-events: none;}
.submenu_willwid:after {border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.68); border-width: 12px; margin-left: -12px;}
.submenu_willwid2:after, .submenu_willwid2:before {bottom: 100%; left: 59%; border: solid transparent; content: " "; height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; pointer-events: none;}
.submenu_willwid2:after {border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.68); border-width: 12px; margin-left: -12px;}
</sryle>
```

**HTML**

```
      <nav class="nav animated fadeInUp m1">
    <ul>
      <li id="menu1"> <a href="javascript:;">About Us</a> </li>
      <li id="menu2"><a href="companies.html">Our Group Companies</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Investor Relations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Social Responsibility</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Media/News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="submenu_willwid" id="submenu1">
    <div class="menu_inner">
      <div class="submenu_col_full">
        <div class="rot_box">
          <div class="rot_box_inner"><a href="company-at-glance.html"><img src="images/menu-tri-1.png">
            <div class="hov"></div>
            </a></div>
        </div>
        <h4><a href="company-at-glance.html">company at a Glance</a></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="submenu_col_full">
        <div class="rot_box">
          <div class="rot_box_inner"><a href="vision.html"><img src="images/menu-tri-2.png">
            <div class="hov"></div>
            </a></div>
        </div>
        <h4><a href="vision.html">Vision and Mission</a></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="submenu_col_full">
        <div class="rot_box">
          <div class="rot_box_inner"><a href="history.html"><img src="images/menu-tri-3.png">
            <div class="hov"></div>
            </a></div>
        </div>
        <h4><a href="history.html">Our History</a></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="submenu_col_full">
        <div class="rot_box">
          <div class="rot_box_inner"><a href="our-strategy.html"><img src="images/menu-tri-4.png">
            <div class="hov"></div>
            </a></div>
        </div>
        <h4><a href="our-strategy.html">Our Strategy</a></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="submenu_col_full">
        <div class="rot_box">
          <div class="rot_box_inner"><a href="board-members.html"><img src="images/menu-tri-5.png">
            <div class="hov"></div>
            </a></div>
        </div>
        <h4><a href="board-members.html">Board Members</a></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="submenu_willwid submenu_willwid2" id="submenu2">
    <div class="menu_inner">
      <div class="submenu_col_full">
        <div class="rot_box">
          <div class="rot_box_inner"><a href="company-at-glance.html"><img src="images/menu-tri-1.png">
            <div class="hov"></div>
            </a></div>
        </div>
        <h4><a href="company-at-glance.html">company at a Glance 2</a></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="submenu_col_full">
        <div class="rot_box">
          <div class="rot_box_inner"><a href="vision.html"><img src="images/menu-tri-2.png">
            <div class="hov"></div>
            </a></div>
        </div>
        <h4><a href="vision.html">Vision and Mission</a></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="submenu_col_full">
        <div class="rot_box">
          <div class="rot_box_inner"><a href="history.html"><img src="images/menu-tri-3.png">
            <div class="hov"></div>
            </a></div>
        </div>
        <h4><a href="history.html">Our History</a></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="submenu_col_full">
        <div class="rot_box">
          <div class="rot_box_inner"><a href="our-strategy.html"><img src="images/menu-tri-4.png">
            <div class="hov"></div>
            </a></div>
        </div>
        <h4><a href="our-strategy.html">Our Strategy</a></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="submenu_col_full">
        <div class="rot_box">
          <div class="rot_box_inner"><a href="board-members.html"><img src="images/menu-tri-5.png">
            <div class="hov"></div>
            </a></div>
        </div>
        <h4><a href="board-members.html">Board Members</a></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#menu1').mouseover(function(){
  $('#submenu1').fadeIn();
});
$('#menu1').mouseleave(function(){
  $('#submenu1').fadeOut();
});

//Menu 2
$('#menu2').mouseover(function(){
  $('#submenu2').fadeIn();
});
$('#menu2').mouseleave(function(){
  $('#submenu2').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Looking for something like this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/qsyg958b/4) ?

Comment: Yes something like this, but I don't have option to move html within LI is there option without changing HTML structure?

Comment: No, first its not a valid structure to make a sub-menu of a menu and second when you move your mouse to the sub-menu it leaves the area of `li` and it makes true the second condition and your sub-menu gets `fadeOut`.

Comment: I think you are correct, I will have to move the sub menu elements within LI, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code for mouseenter and mouseleave event should be as mentioned below. here `stop()` method use for stop running animation.

```
//Menu 1
$('#menu1, #submenu1').mouseover(function(){
    $('#submenu1').stop().fadeIn();
});
$('#menu1, #submenu1').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#submenu1').stop().fadeOut();
});

//Menu 2
$('#menu2, #submenu2').mouseover(function(){
    $('#submenu2').stop().fadeIn();
});
$('#menu2, #submenu2').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#submenu2').stop().fadeOut();
});
```

Check jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qsyg958b/14/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('#menu1,#submenu1').mouseover(function(){
      $('#submenu1').fadeIn();
    });
    $('#menu1,#submenu1').mouseleave(function(){
      $('#submenu1').fadeOut();
    });
```